# How to apply mode function for some columns using agg method with groupby when aggregating using different functions for each column

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, aggregate, feature-engineering

I have a dataframe of numerical and categorical columns which I am trying to group by certain columns and aggregate.

I am trying to apply mode function on categorical columns in a pandas dataframe and other statistical functions like sum,min..etc on other columns in the same dataframe.

I am not able to get the mode for certain column.

What I tried so far is:

`df_agg = df.sort_values(by=['userId', 'num1','num2'],ascending=False).groupby(['userId', 'cat1', 'cat2']).agg({'num3': 'sum', 'num2': 'sum','num1': 'sum', 'num4': 'sum', 'num5':'sum', 'num6':'sum', 'num7': 'min', 'cat3':'mode', 'cat4':'mode'}).reset_index()`

That gives the error: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'mode'.

How can I get mode of these categorical columns in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use lambda function, because `mode` should return multiple first values is selected first value:

```
..., 'cat4':lambda x: x.mode().iat[0]}
```

EDIT: If need all modes:

```
..., 'cat4':lambda x: list(x.mode())).reset_index().explode('cat4')
```

Comment: iat[0] gives me the first value if multiple modes exist? and what if I want one row per mode ?

Comment: @R.A - `iat[0] gives me the first value if multiple modes exist` - yes, exactly. `and what if I want one row per mode` - try `'cat4':lambda x: list(x.mode())` and after solution `df = df.explode('mode')`

Comment: Thanks so much. I am new to Python and dataframe manipulation. Do you recommend any courses or resources to data cleaning and manipulation for machine learning to enhance my experience?

Comment: @R.A - You can check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/tutorials.html)